# Error when applying normalize function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have 400 columns and I am trying to do min-max normalization (row-wise). For the first 200 points I want to do min-max normalization and scale it between 0 and 500 and do the same for the next two hundred points but scale it between 0 and 10.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(500,1000,size=(5, 400)))
def normalize(ds,value):
    normalizedds = []
    normalizedds.extend((ds[:value] - np.min(ds[:value])) / np.max(ds[:value] - np.min(ds[:value])) * 500)
    normalizedds.extend(ds[value:value*2] / np.max(ds[value:value*2]) * 10)
    return normalizedds

normalizeddsList = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df.apply(normalize, value=200, axis=1))
```

I get the following error!

> ---
>
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
>   ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_slice_bound(self, label, side, kind)
>      5166             try:
>   -> 5167                 return self._searchsorted_monotonic(label, side)
>      5168             except ValueError:
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in _searchsorted_monotonic(self, label, side)
>      5127 
>   -> 5128         raise ValueError("index must be monotonic increasing or decreasing")
>      5129
>
> ValueError: index must be monotonic increasing or decreasing
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in 
>   ----> 1 scaledCardList = pd.DataFrame.from_records(originalCardList.apply(scale, pointCount=200, axis=1))
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, broadcast, raw, reduce, result_type, args, **kwds)
>      6926             kwds=kwds,
>      6927         )
>   -> 6928         return op.get_result()
>      6929 
>      6930     def applymap(self, func):
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in get_result(self)
>       184             return self.apply_raw()
>       185 
>   --> 186         return self.apply_standard()
>       187 
>       188     def apply_empty_result(self):
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in apply_standard(self)
>       290 
>       291         # compute the result using the series generator
>   --> 292         self.apply_series_generator()
>       293 
>       294         # wrap results
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in apply_series_generator(self)
>       319             try:
>       320                 for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
>   --> 321                     results[i] = self.f(v)
>       322                     keys.append(v.name)
>       323             except Exception as e:
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in f(x)
>       110 
>       111             def f(x):
>   --> 112                 return func(x, *args, **kwds)
>       113 
>       114         else:
>
> in scale(card, pointCount)
>         1 def scale(card, pointCount):
>         2     scaledCard = []
>   ----> 3     scaledCard.extend((card[:pointCount] - np.min(card[:pointCount])) / np.max(card[:pointCount] - np.min(card[:pointCount])) * 10000)
>         4     scaledCard.extend(card[pointCount:pointCount*2] / np.max(card[pointCount:pointCount*2]) * 100)
>         5     return scaledCard
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in **getitem**(self, key)
>      1111             key = check_bool_indexer(self.index, key)
>      1112 
>   -> 1113         return self._get_with(key)
>      1114 
>      1115     def _get_with(self, key):
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in _get_with(self, key)
>      1116         # other: fancy integer or otherwise
>      1117         if isinstance(key, slice):
>   -> 1118             indexer = self.index._convert_slice_indexer(key, kind="getitem")
>      1119             return self._get_values(indexer)
>      1120         elif isinstance(key, ABCDataFrame):
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\numeric.py in _convert_slice_indexer(self, key, kind)
>       395 
>       396         # translate to locations
>   --> 397         return self.slice_indexer(key.start, key.stop, key.step, kind=kind)
>       398 
>       399     def _format_native_types(
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in slice_indexer(self, start, end, step, kind)
>      5032         slice(1, 3)
>      5033         """
>   -> 5034         start_slice, end_slice = self.slice_locs(start, end, step=step, kind=kind)
>      5035 
>      5036         # return a slice
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in slice_locs(self, start, end, step, kind)
>      5252         end_slice = None
>      5253         if end is not None:
>   -> 5254             end_slice = self.get_slice_bound(end, "right", kind)
>      5255         if end_slice is None:
>      5256             end_slice = len(self)
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_slice_bound(self, label, side, kind)
>      5168             except ValueError:
>      5169                 # raise the original KeyError
>   -> 5170                 raise err
>      5171 
>      5172         if isinstance(slc, np.ndarray):
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_slice_bound(self, label, side, kind)
>      5162         # we need to look up the label
>      5163         try:
>   -> 5164             slc = self.get_loc(label)
>      5165         except KeyError as err:
>      5166             try:
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\numeric.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
>       477         except (TypeError, NotImplementedError):
>       478             pass
>   --> 479         return super().get_loc(key, method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
>       480 
>       481     @cache_readonly
>
> ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
>      2897                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
>      2898             except KeyError:
>   -> 2899                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
>      2900         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
>      2901         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:
>
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Float64HashTable.get_item()
>
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Float64HashTable.get_item()
>
> KeyError: (200.0, 'occurred at index 0')

​
​
​

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: @AMC Have added a reproducible example. Thanks

Comment: What version of Python and pandas do you have?

Comment: @AMC! For the example here it seems to be working fine. It throws error for the dataset I have

Comment: @sophros: python : 3.7.3.final.0, pandas : 0.25.3

Comment: Given your comment on the "dataset you have" without it (or a nailed down dataset that exemplifies the problem) nobody will be able to help you out. Minimal reproducible example is absolutely necessary.